# Netsh wlan hostednetwork only 5 GHz

Tags: windows-7, netsh, wifi

I have a hostednetwork installed via:

```
netsh wlan set hostednetwork mode=allow ssid=Hotspot key=7Tutorials
```

when I start it with:

```
netsh wlan start Hotspot
```

it starts a WLAN Hotspot in 2,4GHz Net which works fine.

So my question is: **Is there a way to use the 5GHz Net only?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that the Adapter was not able to start a 5 GHz hostednetwork.

But I did not find a way to force only one type.

Answer (score 0):

In fact, when your device is already connected to a network, hostednetwork technology uses the same channel (so same frequency) to emit the hosted wifi.

Connect your device to a 5Ghz wifi and start hostednetwork: the emitted network should be in 5GHz.